# use existing Microsoft Runtime environment for own language/compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, runtime, abstract-syntax-tree

We have an own language and a compiler build in our software. In the past the compile and execute was done by our own code. So starting with a new version of our Software we think about a speedup of the runtime. So basically at the Point we have the AST we think about pushing the whole execution into native X86 instructions which is quite complicated. Anyway there are some runtimes from Mirosoft which are able to make “just in time compiling and executing code”. 
So the idea is to create the common AST for our language and push the result in some way into such existing Microsoft runtime system to not invent the wheel again. Does anybody has a good starting point for such a task ?

Regards
  Markus

Comment: See `ilasm` and `ildasm`

Comment: thank you, this was fast 8-) after make a Brief Review on this Information it seems this is all to create dll/exe file but no hint to make this "in Memory" without creating external files

Comment: Markus: To confirm... you want to push the AST to something which will evaluate and execute the expression of the AST on demand?

Comment: Currently the execution is based on a recursive run on a annotate AST. Goal is to translate the AST into some intermediate language (like maybe  CLI) to run it direct on the native hardware instead of interpretation of the tree on runtime.